# Trying to write leaky code in Winforms

Tags: c, winforms, visual-studio-2010

To learn how memory and GDI leaks occur, and how to remove such leaks I am trying to write sample codes in Winforms (using C). I wrote simple application that displays some characters  on  a GUI.

How do I make it leaky in terms of memory and GDI resource?

Comment: Use lots of resources the you need to explicitly close and/or unmanaged code.

Comment: Well, look up how to prevent memory leaks on this site and do the opposite :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leak GDI resources, then creating things like fonts or brushes and not disposing them should do the trick, these basically really on you to call [`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free there associated resources (of course these will get cleaned up when you exit the process).

You can track leaks by checking the creation of the objects listed by `DeleteObject` as requiring deletion, you can also get a bit more advanced and check the outstanding GDI handles in the PEB & TEB. [`EnumObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should also be helpful in this regard.

Comment: +1: Bitmaps in allocated screen-compatible DC's (neither of which you release) are also outstanding ways to eat resources lickety-split.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with GDI, but getting a program to leak elsewhere is really easy. You just have to forget to free any memory that you previously malloc'd.

Example:

```
int someFunc() {
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(50);

    // Do stuff

    // Should free here like this:
    // free(buf);
    return 4;
}
```

If you don't free it, that memory is leaked, as it is inaccessible, yet still allotted to your program.